# How can I hide phone navigation buttons?

Tags: javascript, navigation

I'm writing a simple JS game and trying to figure out whether it is possible to hide phone's navigation buttons (back, menu, hide) once I enter full screen mode.

Comment: No, this is not possible from Javascript.

Comment: It is possible with Progressive Web App to go full screen with no tool bar or navigation, can you gives us more informations about your application? Do you use PWA? If so, can you provide manifest.json file?